# Can I detect what webserver a website is using?

Tags: internet, http, webserver

Is there any program or command that I can use to detect what webserver a website is using? With webserver I mean in software i.e. IIS 6, Apache or nginx.

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097472/how-to-detect-web-server-type

Comment: I like: https://w3bin.com/ but it's not always going to be accurate due to CDNs such as CloudFlare, etc

Comment: Since the tools `wget` and `curl` will not become outdated (and probably many following HTTP versions will report [the `Server:` header](https://www.iana.org/assignments/message-headers/message-headers.xhtml)), this could be reopened.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**raw:**

```
curl -I duckduckgo.com
```

**filtered:**

```
curl -s -I duckduckgo.com|grep Server
```

or

```
curl -s -I duckduckgo.com|sed -n '/^Server:/p'
```

or übercool

```
curl -s -I duckduckgo.com|awk '$1~/Server:/ {print $2}'
```

or for poser

```
curl -s -I duckduckgo.com|sed -n 's/^S[erv]*: //p'
```

**only for unixoide OS!!!**

Comment: 1+ for "übercool" and "poser". Indeed SED+AWK Users are übercool posers :D

Comment: works with `cURL on Windows` as well

Comment: I would recommend suggesting `curl --head` instead of `curl -I` (uppercase i), which I misread as `curl -l` (lowercase L).

Answer (score 67):

You can use [Netcraft What's That Site Running](http://uptime.netcraft.com/up/graph) for a one off query.

You can use

```
wget --save-headers superuser.com
```

Which will dump the server headers into a new file index.html which you can then view in a text editor.

Eg, for this site:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Tue, 16 Mar 2010 22:54:59 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Date: Tue, 16 Mar 2010 22:54:58 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 119466
```

If you need a one-liner to just report the webserver type only and filter out the unwanted stuff then use:

```
wget -q -O- --save-headers superuser.com | grep '^[Ss]erver:' | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: for Windows users `curl` is better, GnuWin's ported `wget` doesn't return anything useful

Comment: Does not work for me. Linux Mint 20.

Comment: On Windows, `curl --head superuser.com`

Answer (score 4):

For a public website, you can use Netcraft - http://netcraft.com/.  It allows you to plug in a website's address, and it will analyze the headers and tell you the webserver in use.